# Should a primary key be also a required property in Realm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have 3 questions about the same topic:

1. How can I **prevent** saving an object to Realm with a nil primaryKey?
2. Are primaryKeys in Realm implicitly requiredProperties?
3. Which one of below is true?

1.option:

```
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"myUniqueID";
}

+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)requiredProperties {
    return @[@"myUniqueID", @"name", @"surname"];
}
```

2.option:

```
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"myUniqueID";
}

+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)requiredProperties {
    return @[@"name", @"surname"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special treatment of primary keys with respect to nullability. If your primary key is of a type that is nullable by default (i.e., an `NSString`), then `nil` is a valid value for that primary key. Note, however, that only a single object can be stored with a `nil` primary key, due to the constraint that primary keys must be unique.

If you wish for an `NSString` primary key to be non-nil, you should include it in the array returned by `+requiredProperties`.